# Allow remote access to Mysql Server 8 on Windows 10

Tags: mysql, windows

I like to connecto from my webpage to my home local SQL server 8.0 running on Win10.

I have created a new Root user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

on all other questions Its mentioned to remove  `bind-address = 127.0.0.1` but i cant locate the `my.cnf` file on C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\

how can i solve this?

is there any way i could restrict the connection so that it's only from the web domain.com i have?

Comment: Why do you want to connect from your website to your local mysql? Do it the other way around, reach out from your local computer to your website if you want to upload or download anything.

Comment: no, since i have other things running on my local server and the hosting does not allow me to connect remotly to their SQL so i have to reach from the hosting to my localhost :S

Comment: Change hosting provider or develop a simple api that allows you to upload or download data from the server. What you want is really unsafe and really unprofessional.

Comment: well its for a testing environment, and i rather test the option to allow remote access to the local server in this case.

Comment: Your test database should be on your webserver as well, preferably a different mysql instance.

Comment: thanks, but i need the help with the question asked, not defining the environment im working on.